# Confused about length contraction and aberration

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, lorentz-symmetry, length

Einstein states that a moving object's shape changes due to the length contraction. But people had done such an experiment: Taking photos to a moving object, but they didn't find Lorentz contraction, instead, the object on picture just takes a rotation, which is the aberration. I'm confused about the two effect. Is there self-contradiction？

Comment: Do you have references for the experiments? Sounds interesing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a sphere moving close to the speed of light look like?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47224/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lorentz transformation gives the relationship between the time and space *coordinates* of two inertial reference frames in relative motion.

As such, it is *coordinate* length contraction and *coordinate* time dilation that results.

Thus, in SR, *observing* (or *measuring*) length contraction does not mean to *photograph* length contraction.  Rather, it means recording events:   "the front of the rod was at this location at the same (coordinate) time as the rear of the rod was at this other location; the rod's (coordinate) length is thus..."

From the article "[Photography in Special Relativity](http://users.monash.edu.au/~leo/research/movies/sr/sr-wmv.html)":

> ### Observation vs Photography
>
> In Special Relativity there is a very specific meaning to the word
>   observer.  An observer is one of an infinite collection, in space and
>   time, of robots whose sole task in life is to record the time and
>   location of each detected event. When we say that an observation was
>   made we simply mean that the space and time coordinates of an event
>   have been recorded.
>
> A photograph is a record of all of the photons that were received at
>   the focal point of the camera at the time the photograph was taken.
>
> These are fundamentally different processes and they give us very
>   different information about the universe.