# Calculating an "apparent" speed of a beam in a medium

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, optics, kinematics

While thinking about relativity, one question sparked my curiosity. If we could observe the trajectory of a light beam by using some partially opaque medium, like smoke, to make it visible, we'd not perceive light as moving at $c$. As the light rays approached the observer, they would appear to move slightly faster than $c$, and as they moved away, slightly slower, only moving at $c$ exactly in the point where the light ray is at a right angle to the line of sight. This is because the reflected light from the smoke would take longer to reach the observer the further from the observer it is emitted.

What would be the exact formula for this  apparent velocity of the light ray? I can't see a straighforward way of computing it. It would be a function of the distance of the light front at the moment it is closest to the observer in the trajectory, the time elapsed (positive or negative) from that moment, and the speed of light in the medium.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: I challenge your assertion that the light would appear to move faster than c as it approaches, how did you come to this conclusion?

Specifically, it should appear to move at a speed `cos(angle) * c`.

Comment: @Turksarama I don't know if there is a better terminology but that's not really what I meant. I'm not talking about the actual speed light propagates but the speed in which the observer will see the fog "lighting up". If light travels straight into the observer he'll see all the fog in front of him lighting up simultaneously, up to an infinite distance, creating the illusion of an infinite speed of light.

Comment: Ah I think I get what you're saying now.  It will probably be `c + c * sin(angle)` from picturing it in my head.  I might come back and do an explanation of my thinking if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: Drawing triangles, I think the answer is $c/(1-cos \theta)$.  This is very large as it comes towards you from far away, as the light paths are almost the same, drops to $c$ as it goes past and $\theta=0$, and drops to $c/2$ as the ray goes away from you.     BTW there is no violation of relativity as this is an 'apparent' velocity: if you were measuring events in this setup you would correct for the propagation times of the light signals.

Comment: It is the velocity of light in the medium, which is always less than the c of vacuum, thus we have the cerenkov effect.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow Nice! I did not expect to find a violation of relativity. The motivation was that I was wondering about the "realness" of spacetime diagrams themselves. Some interesting things happen when we focus on observations instead of actual spacetime coordinates. For instance, although moving spheres contract when moving close to the speed of light, they still look perfectly spherical, because the observation delay perfectly cancels the effect. [Link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47224/what-does-a-sphere-moving-close-to-the-speed-of-light-look-like)

Comment: There’s a neat application of this — look up “apparent superluminal motion”. It appeared that some astrophysical objects were traveling faster than light, causing much controversy, but it was really because of this effect.

Comment: @knzhou Hurray! The wikipedia article has the formula and derivation I was looking for! Thank you so much

Comment: @someone_else Since it was of value to you I'll type it up in an answer, since comments get deleted pretty often!

Comment: @knzhou I don't understand your edit to the title of the question. The main point of the question is not about the superluminal velocity, but the precise description of the apparent velocity of the light beam

Comment: @someone_else I adjusted it, better now? Since you are the question asker, you're also free to rollback any edits you don't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a real effect called [apparent superluminal motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion), with the apparent velocity being
$$v' = \frac{v \sin \theta}{1 - v \cos \theta}$$
in units where $c = 1$. Here, $v'$ is an apparent tangential velocity, defined as $v' = r \omega$ where $r$ is the distance, $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the object in the sky, and $\theta$ is the angle the velocity makes with the radial direction. This isn't quite in the variables that you want (the time and the distance of closest approach) but it should be relatively straightforward to convert it.

For sufficiently large $v$ and $\theta$, $v'$ may exceed the speed of light. Of course it's just "apparent" motion, not a real violation of the speed of light limit, but there was briefly controversy over such observations until somebody figured this out.